# VBA Using WMI to monitor performance during script execution

Tags: vba, performance, server, wmi

I'm trying to monitor memory load and CPU usage during the execution of a VBA script. Both the monitoring (VBA, WMI) and the script are running on the same software (Statistica) on a server. I'm able to monitor the performance metrics before and after the execution but not during. Do you know of any solution where I can monitor on the background and still run whatever I want? Don't need to stick to WMI, all solutions are more than welcome!